# {0} array filling assignment in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I read that using this assignment declaration

```
int arr[n][n]={0};
```

will give a nxn matrix full of 0's, but when i run it it doesn't give 0's at particular locations, in some cases they even look like addresses, specifically near the end arr[n][n] and arr[n][1], where all other are assigned to 0.. What is making this assignment happen? Using a for loop to fill this array does not produce this problem.

Edit: n in this case is any positive integer >= 2

Seems like `{number}` only affects the first element and leaves the rest. The following statement sets all elements to 0. Thanks to the guys in the comments for actually answering the question.

```
int arr[n][n]={};
```

Comment: What are the valid indexes for an array of `n` elements? Don't forget that array indexes are *zero based*.

Comment: Show the definition of n.

Comment: You could use `memset` instead of a for loop. Actually, you could use `std::vector`. But I guess you have your reasons for using arrays. ;-)

Comment: As for your problem about initializing the array, there is *no* problem. That definition, assuming `n` is a compile-time constant, will do what you want. The problem seem to be stemming from your use of `n` as an index.

Comment: `{0}` does NOT initialize all elements with 0, only the first one. Instead you can use `std::fill_n`.

Comment: @DimChtz it DOES initialize all elements to 0.

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't let some zeros confuse you. Take a look: http://cpp.sh/5kd5. Just because you see zeros doesn't mean it actually initialize all the elements.

Comment: @DimChtz It does. The same goes with `a[n][n]{};`.

Comment: @ZDF Let me rephrase: `a[n]{some_value}` will NOT initialize all `n` elements with `some_value`, just the first one.

Comment: @DimChtz: but what will happen to the rest? Are they undefined or 0?

Comment: @Stefan Rest should be `0`. My point is that by saying `{0}` will initialize all elements with zeros means that it works with any value inside the brackets which is invalid.

Comment: @Stefan Even `{}` will initialize all values to zeros. But `{value}` means that ONLY the first one will get the value of `val` and the rest will be 0.

Comment: @DimChtz From standard, if I correctly interpreted it: _If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there is no brace-or-equalinitializer,
from an empty initializer list (8.5.4)._

Comment: First Arrays are indexed from 0 through n-1. So element n doesn't belong to the array. 2 ` in some cases they even look like addresses` I guess you didn't read the elements the right way. Remember you are handling 2D array not one. So with too loops you can: `for(int i(0); i < n; i++){for(int j(0); j < n; j++) std::cout << array[i][j] << ", ";}`. I think you wrote: std::cout << `array[i]` which prints the addresses instead of the values.

Comment: @ZDF That's exactly what I said.

Comment: @DimChtz what you say is irrelevant for the problem. No one claimed that the written 0 is used to initialize all array elements.

Comment: @DimChtz So, you're questioning the source of initial values. Correct, but for this specific case it makes no difference. I guess `{0}` adds a bit of clarity (I'm using `{}`). Nobody is claiming that `{42}` initializes each element to `42`.

Comment: @DimChtz Does it initialize all the elements to zero or not? It is very simple: it does. You claimed it didn't, and I corrected you. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @juanchopanza And I rephrased just to be cleared: "`a[n]{some_value}` will NOT initialize all `n` elements with `some_value`". I just got the impression that OP was thinking that "`{5}` = initialize each element to `5`", that's why I said what I said.

Answer (score 1):

> specifically near the end `arr[n][n]` and `arr[n][1]`

Both `arr[n][n]` and `arr[n][1]` are invalid accesses, using these indexes results in undefined behaviour.

The range of valid indexes are [0, n-1], e.g. the last element is `arr[n - 1][n - 1]`.

Comment: I can access `arr[n][n]`, `arr[n][1]` without any problems.

Comment: @user136128 Nope, you cannot. You already documented the problems you observed in your question.

Comment: @user136128 There are two kinds of "can" - you may be *able* to do something, or you may be *allowed* to do something. You are not allowed to do this. Just like in the real world, not getting caught red-handed does not imply that you weren't doing anything wrong.

Comment: @user136128 Again, don't forget that array indexes are *zero based*. That is, an array of `n` elements will have valid indexes in the range of `0` to `n - 1` (inclusive). Going out of bounds (like using `n` as index) leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Also remember that C++ does *not* have any kind of range-check for indexes. And neither does it have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).